# LINQ Projected Filtering C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to filter my LINQ query based on an included table but am having some trouble.

Here is the original statement, which works:

```
return 
    this.ObjectContext.People.
        Include("Careers").
        Include("Careers.Titles").
        Include("Careers.Titles.Salaries");
```

Now I'm trying to filter on Careers using projected filtering but am having trouble.  It  compiles but it leaves out the Titles and Salaries tables, which causes runtime errors, and I can't seem to add those tables back in:

```
var query1 = (
    from c in 
    this.ObjectContext.People.
        Include("Careers").
        Include("Careers.Titles").
        Include("Careers.Titles.Salaries")
    select new
    {
        c,
        Careers = from Careers in c.Careers
                  where Careers.IsActive == true
                  select Careers
    });

    var query = query1.AsEnumerable().Select(m => m.c);
    return query.AsQueryable();
```

How can I include the titles and salaries tables in the filtered query?

Comment: Can you include how People is linked to Careers?

Comment: Careers has a foreign key to People fk_Person

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your query considerably, which should resolve your issue. I'm assuming that you want all people with at least 1 active career:

```
var query = 
    from c in 
    this.ObjectContext.People.
        Include("Careers").
        Include("Careers.Titles").
        Include("Careers.Titles.Salaries")
    where c.Careers.Any(c => c.IsActive);

return query;
```

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't specify... I want all people with only the active careers listed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like,

```
var query = from p in ObjectContext.People
            join c in ObjectContext.Careers on p equals c.Person
            where c.IsActive
            select p;
```

Comment: Still having trouble getting the titles and salaries tables back with it.  If I join those tables too, it doesn't come back in the same form as it does with the Includes.